# How to use the 'inherit' CSS keyword in makeStyles() for MaterialUI 4?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, nested

```
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  button: {
    backgroundColor: '#417bff',
    width: '200px',
    color: 'white',
    '&:hover': {
      transform: 'scale(1.03)',
      backgroundColor: 'inherit' # <<<<
    }
  }
})

const BaseButton = ({ context, href }) => {
  const classes = useStyles()

  return (
    <Button className={classes.button} variant="contained" href={href}>
      {context}
    </Button>
  )
}
```

I am trying to ensure that when the button is in a hover state, it will inherit the backgroundColor value of #417bff. I want to implement props within the styling and don't wish to keep repeating the color value for every pseudo selector. The aim is that when the button BaseButton component is called, the props just takes in a single value of the button background color and any state i.e. active, hover etc. inherits the parent color.

I can only use MaterialUI 4 as this is legacy code.